# How can I replicate this spiral ripple effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to recreate this effect, or something similar, in Illustrator. I've tried messing around with blends and the transform effect, but so far I haven't had much luck wrapping my brain around how this is done.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can think of a way to get something similar in Photoshop. Just two black squares and blurred rings used as a displacement map. [see rough example](https://imgur.com/CBoC8tS).  I don't think it could be automated Illustrator to be honest. I suppose you could always just redraw it manually with the pen tool, or make it in Photoshop then auto trace in Illustrator.

Comment: Drawing it manually is the fastest way to finish the design. As it is just one design repeated, you need to draw just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit convoluted but making two shapes with the the pucker and bloat
filter, and setting them opposite one another, group them together and then use the Twirl tool will give you something close, that could be finessed.